# Cannot find a differ supporting object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to perform rest requests in order using switchMap(...)from RxJs.

Object:

```
export class Transaction {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public unique_id: string,
    public name: string,
    public status: string,
    public type: string,
    public created_at: Date
  ) {}
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-details',
  templateUrl: './transaction-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-details.component.scss']
})
export class TransactionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  processingLogs: ProcessingLogs = new ProcessingLogs(null, null, null, null, null);
  transaction: Transaction;

  constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService,
              private processingLogsService: ProcessingLogsService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
        if(params['id']) {
          return this.transactionService.get(params['id']);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if(value != null) {
        this.transaction = value;
      }
    });

    this.route.params.pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
        if (transaction.unique_id) {
          return this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(transaction.unique_id);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if (value != null) {
        this.processingLogs = value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  map(params=>params['id']),
  switchMap(idParameter=> this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(idParameter))
).subscribe(logList=>
  value => this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(value.unique_id)
);
```

First I would like to to load `transactionService.get(params['id'])` using `id` from the http link.
Second when the Object `Transaction` is loaded I would like to load `getProcessingLogsList(transaction.unique_id)` using the `unique_id` loaded from the first request. I get error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3152)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9246)
```

And the page data is empty. How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Per the error message, `NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays` - you're trying to run an `ngFor` loop over an *object*, instead.

Comment: Looks like I'm not implementing properly switchMap. Can you give some advice how to implement it?